# How to check if a directory is still used in a process

Tags: backup, bash

I have some shared directory `/path/to/dir`. I'm running a backup process on that directory. The process is running on server A while I have only access on server B. So when the backup process is finished on server A, I'll have the data in the shared directory `/path/to/dir` which is also available on server B.

Now I have a bash script on server B which may only run when the backup process is finished. Because I can not access the other server I was thinking about the following:

Can I check if `/path/to/dir` is still in use by the backup process and only run my script if the process isn't running anymore on the directory?

I don't know if it's important to know it's a shared directory(NFS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution: Create a lockfile on the share that only exists while the job is running and will be deleted on server A once that job is done.

On server B you just check if this file exists and if it does, wait until it's gone.

Comment: Hm nice solution. I'll try this. I'll accept it in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

Set a producing app A to create the files as `example_output.tar.gz.part` and only after it is sure everything is finished, rename to `example_output.tar.gz`

Set a consuming app B to ignore the `*.part` files and process all files that don't match `*.part`

This scheme is recognizable, because it is used in many consumer applications (web browsers or scp clients come to mind).

This way you don't need any lockfile and you can have multiple consumers. A lockfile is always a potential cause of failure if an old one is left over after an application dies (or server is rebooted).